# Capturing Enter key in textbox doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my View, I try to tie an event to the Enter key by the following XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="{Binding FieldsTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False" >
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding AddFieldCommand}"></KeyBinding>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

The `AddFieldCommand` exists in my ViewModel as a property:

```
public ICommand AddFieldCommand { get; private set; }
```

In the ViewModel Constructor the following `RelayCommand` exists.

```
AddFieldCommand = new RelayCommand(AddField);
```

And from the `RelayCommand` the method `AddField` is called.

```
public void AddField()
{
   Console.WriteLine("AddField Method")
}
```

This doesn't work - the AddField method is never called. Can anybody help?

Comment: isn't that caused by `AcceptsReturn="false"`?

Comment: @KingKing No, the `AcceptsReturn="false"` prevents linebreaks. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptsreturn(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: have you tried setting some ***breakpoint*** in the method `AddField`? Don't expect the Console to appear and print some message for you to see.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, I have tried breakpoints in the method - the breakpoints are never activated.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the the .InputBindings aren't working in this scenario. Keyboard input handling is probably being hijacked by the TextBox.

Assuming you want to stick to the MVVM pattern and avoid event-handling code in the code-behind, I'd probably choose to create a custom implementation of the TextBox - call it a 'SubmitTextBox'

The custom SubmitTextBox could automatically hook up to the PreviewKeyDown event, and monitor the Enter key.

You could further adhere to MVVM by adding an ICommand DP to handle the 'Submit' event.

Something like this ...

```
public class SubmitTextBox : TextBox
{
    public SubmitTextBox()
        : base()
    {
        PreviewKeyDown += SubmitTextBox_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    private void SubmitTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
            if (this.SubmitCommand != null && this.SubmitCommand.CanExecute(this.Text))
            {
                // Note this executes the command, and returns
                // the current value of the textbox.
                this.SubmitCommand.Execute(this.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The command to execute when the text is submitted (Enter is pressed).
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand SubmitCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SubmitCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SubmitCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SubmitCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubmitCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SubmitCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SubmitTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

And your XAML would end up looking like this:

```
<custom:SubmitTextBox 
  x:Name="txtFields"
  Text="{Binding FieldsTextProperty}"
  SubmitCommand="{Binding AddFieldCommand}" 
  Height="23" 
  TextWrapping="NoWrap"
  Background="#FFCBEECD" />
```

Hope that helps :)

UPDATE: To clarify, the SubmitCommand I created returns the current text in the textbox as a parameter. In order to use this with the MVVM-Light toolkit, you'll need to create a RelayCommand that can accept the type 'string'.

```
public RelayCommand<string> AddFieldCommand { get; private set; }

public ViewModelConstructor()
{
   AddFieldCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(AddField);
}

private void AddField(string text)
{
   // Do something
}
```

I hope that clears things up a litte :)

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain how I use the SubmitTextBox Class in my ViewModel - I have same trouble doing it..

Comment: There's no need to use the SubmitTextBox in your ViewModel. An instance of the new TextBox is created in XAML ... all you need to do is bind to it. On your ViewModel, create an ICommand (RelayCommand if you're using MVVMLight) that performs the operation you'd like when the text is submitted. Then bind that command to the 'SubmitCommand' on the SubmitTextBox. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: So this should be enough in the ViewModel? `AddFieldCommand = new RelayCommand(SubmitCommand);` And yes, I am using MVVMLight :)

Comment: Looking at your original code, I'd expect it to read: **AddFieldCommand = new RelayCommand(AddField);** ... but yes, that's the basic idea. Then make sure you have the **SubmitCommand="{Binding AddFieldCommand}"** command binding on your SubmitTextBox in your XAML.

Comment: I get some Binding Errors: 'FieldsTextProperty' property not found on 'object' ''ClassData''. BindingExpression:Path=FieldsTextProperty; DataItem='ClassData'; target element is 'SubmitTextBox' (Name='txtFields'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
'AddFieldCommand' property not found on 'object' 'ClassData'. BindingExpression:Path=AddFieldCommand; DataItem='ClassData'; target element is 'SubmitTextBox' (Name='txtFields'); target property is 'SubmitCommand' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: I'm not too clear on what this is, as I can't see you viewmodel code, etc ... but since my SubmitTextBox returns a textbox value (string) parameter with the SubmitCommand, make sure you create a RelayCommand of type 'string'. For example ...

`AddFieldCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(AddField);`

However, if you do this, you'll need to update your AddField method to accept a string argument. Alternatively, you could just change the `this.SubmitCommand.Execute(this.Text);` to `this.SubmitCommand.Execute();`

Comment: ... I've updated the answer to clarify this. It's a bit hard to show in the comments. If you're still stuck, lets take this discussion into chat.